# Why does nginx redirect to a strange URL?

Tags: linux, redirection, nginx

I had just set up nginx on my server. I have PHP and everything working okay. Except when I try the URL

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/123
```

I get redirected to

```
http://_/123
```

but when I try the url

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/123/
```

It works just as I want it to. How can I get nginx to treat the slashless url decently?

Answer (score 3):

Check your php. I had similar problem when I had

```
redirect($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
```

in my login.php. I replaced it with

```
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
```

and now everything is fine. `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is the first domain in server_name directive in nginx and `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is domain in request.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your config:

```
server_name_in_redirect off;
```

See the relevant docs here:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name_in_redirect